# Pass data from controller to view using JQuery Ajax in Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

I have a laravel app having a modal in which I wish to perform a search in the database and display info in the same modal without reloading the page (which would cause the modal to disappear).

For that I am using jquery/ajax to pass data to the controller and get result.

However I am not getting the correct format of data returned from the controller. Or maybe should I change something in the jQuery/AJAX.

The result I am getting is:

```
{{ $temoin->nnid }} {{ $temoin->nom }}  {{ $temoin->postnom }}  {{ $temoin->datenaissance }}
```

Any advice?

The code:

route

```
Route::post('/nouveau_ne', ['uses' => 'AdulteController@rechercheAdulte']);
```

the jQuery/AJAX

```
$("#search_witness_btn").on('click', function() {
    var nnid_temoin = $('#nnid_temoin').val();
    if ($.trim(nnid_temoin) != '') {
        alert('ok '+nnid_temoin);
        $.post('/nouveau_ne',{nnid_temoin:nnid_temoin}, function(data) {
            $('#result_temoin').html(data);
        });
    } else {
        alert('ok '+nnid_temoin);
    }
});
```

The Controller

```
$nnid_temoin = $request->input('nnid_temoin');

$temoin = t_adulte::join('t_individus', 't_adultes.nnid', '=', 't_individus.nnid')
    ->select(['t_individus.nnid','t_individus.nom','t_individus.postnom','t_adultes.datenaissance'])
    ->where('t_adultes.nnid','=',$nnid_temoin)
    ->get();

$result = '<td>{{ $temoin->nnid }}</td><td>{{ $temoin->nom }}</td><td>{{ $temoin->postnom }}</td><td>{{ $temoin->datenaissance }}</td>';
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution Found**

I hade to change this:

```
$result = '<td>{{ $temoin->nnid }}</td><td>{{ $temoin->nom }}</td><td>{{ 
$temoin->postnom }}</td><td>{{ $temoin->datenaissance }}</td>';
return $result;
```

to this:

```
foreach ($temoin as $temoin) {

        $nnid=$temoin->nnid;
        $nom=$temoin->nom;
        $postnom=$temoin->postnom;
        $date=$temoin->datenaissance;

        return '<td class="nnidtemoin" id="nnidtemoin">'.$nnid.'</td><td>'.$nom.'</td><td>'.$postnom.'</td><td>'.$date.'</td>';
        # code...
    }
```

many thanks @all

Answer (score 0):

Your $result string should have the values, not the variables.  You are not running the resulting string through your template engine to handle the bindings.

Comment: #user3720435... thank you for the tip, let me look at that and get back with results

Comment: #user3720435 thanks for the tip, it woked finally. I posted the solution